# Codemagic not signing my app for distribution

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

i'm trying to distribute an app made with flutter, i've tryied using automatic sign and manual sign, but both of them fails.

This is the log for manual sign:

```
== Use manually uploaded iOS code signing files ==

Saved Provisioning Profile distribuicao.mobileprovision to '/Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/tmpgnz196ow.mobileprovision'
Saved Code Signing Certificate ios_distribution.p12 to '/Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/tmp6no2nnan.p12'
> keychain initialize
Initialize new keychain to store code signing certificates at /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db
Create keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db
Set keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db timeout to "no timeout"
Set keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db to system default keychain
Unlock keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db

> keychain add-certificates --certificate /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/tmp6no2nnan.p12 --certificate-password @env:CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD
Add certificates to keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/tmp6no2nnan.p12
Add certificate /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/tmp6no2nnan.p12 to keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db
security: SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)
Unable to add certificate /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/tmp6no2nnan.p12 to keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/22-09-21_lxer72eq.keychain-db


Build failed :|
Failed to add certificate to keychain
```

Answer (score 0):

as the error message says I think `CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD` variable has incorrect password

```
security: SecKeychainItemImport: MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)
```